# Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: The pipe 'translate' could not be found - ionic 3 with angular 6

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngx-translate

I'm a begginer, so be patient with me, pls!!

Can't understand what to do to make this thing work!
Been searching but no answer could help me.

Pipes are working in my restaurant-register page, but can't use it on my restaurant-info component (used in restaurant-register.html).

Here are my files:
**app.module.ts**
...

```
import {TranslateLoader, TranslateModule} from "@ngx-translate/core";
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from "@ngx-translate/http-loader";
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
...
imports: [
          HttpClientModule,
          TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
              provide: TranslateLoader,
              useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
              deps: [HttpClient]
            }
          }),
...
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

**register-restaurant.html** - Works perfectly

```
<ion-content padding margin-top="2em">
  <restaurant-info #restaurantInfo></restaurant-info>

  <button ion-button full
          type="submit"
          [disabled]="!theRestaurant.signupRestaurantForm.valid"
          (click)="onSubmit(theRestaurant.signupRestaurantForm.valid)">
    <ion-icon name="archive"></ion-icon>&nbsp;{{'Save' | translate}} 
  </button>
```

...

**restaurant-info.html** - Where i get "The pipe 'translate' could not be found" error
...

```
<ion-list>
    <h1>{{'Restaurant Name' | translate}}</h1>
```

...

I have no "import {TranslateService}" in restaurant-info.ts file because i only need to use translate in html file. Even if i import it, it makes no difference!

What do i need to do?

Comment: translate 8.0.0
http-loader 3.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Try importing TranslateModule in the RestaurantModule

Comment: I've tried that and some other things i saw when searching for a solution.
It makes no difference because i don't make use of TranslateModule in ts file.

Answer (score 0):

One solution (maybe not the most elegant) is using get() method from TranslateService.

In ts file create a function to tanslate:

```
private translateKey(key: string): string {
    let translated = '';
    this.translateService.get(key).subscribe(text => translated = text);
    return translated;
}
```

Now use translateKey function in html template view:

```
<strong>{{translateKey('Name:')}}</strong> {{store.clientName}}
```

Now it's working...